# Android 6.0 no muestra errores logcat Huawei

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

ayer actualicé la versión de mi huawei p8 a android 6.0 y hoy me encuentro que no se muestran los mensajes de error en el logcat, solo me muestra este mensaje al ocurrir un error:

```
  [ 06-06 09:02:00.624  2929: 2929 E/         ]
  process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
```

Y otro mensaje que no para de salir es este:

```
mSecurityInputMethodService is null
```

Buscando este último solo encontré una persona que había puesto el logcat de su huawei p8 http://pastebin.com/2B34bnCM que es muy parecido al mío.

Otro comportamiento extraño es que al compilar la aplicación se instala bien en el dispositivo, pero el mensaje de android studio "installing APK" no desaparece.

¿Alguien sabe si se me escapa algo?

Gracias por la ayuda.
Un saludo.

Comment: Puede que sea una pregunta tonta, pero ¿has habilitado el modo desarrollador en el móvil con la nueva versión?

Comment: Si si claro está habilitado, la configuración del dispositivo se quedó igual que antes de actualizar.

Comment: Hola amigos este problema lo he visto pero no lo resolví y fue precisamente con un Huawei! =0 Realizaré una búsqueda en internet para ver si encuentro alguna solución!

Comment: Muchas gracias a las dos ^^, yo también sigo en la búsqueda pero creo que tocará restablecer los valores de fábrica -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer es un detalle con esta marca de celulares, no se específicamente los modelos pero en base a esta [**respuesta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18395092/250260).

**Esto aplica solo para los equipos Huawei.**

Encontré también en la especificación de este dispositivo, el escribir el código: `*#*#2846579#*#*` para abrir un menú que por default esta escondido.

http://helpdesk.houdinisoft.com/products/huaweim865-ascend-264

Así que abriendo ese menú vamos a `Project Menu` > `Background Setting` > `Log setting`
definimos mostrar el log con `log switch` y el nivel con `log level setting`.

Con esto ya puedo visualizar los mensajes en el `LogCat`.

---

#### Actualización : **Android 8.0 o posterior**

Se teclea el código : `*#*#2846579#*#*`

y se selecciona la opción **AP Log**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: =0 Muchas gracias! al fin puedo ver los errores estaba ya descargando la versión anterior para hacer un downgrade y perder la garantía, muuy agradecido!