# ¿No me aparecen las excepciones en tiempo de ejecución en android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, programación-móvil

Estoy haciendo pruebas con un dispositivo android programando, pero algo pasa cuando ocurre un excepción con este dispositivo no se muestra en el logcat el detalle del la excepción ni nada, pero si conecto otro dispositivo y corro la misma aplicación en el logcat si se muestra todo el detalle de las excepciones. Quien me podría echar una mano.

El telefono es: Huawey Gplay Mini 
Android:4.4.2

El codigo de la ecepcione es:

```
  final Intent siguiente = new Intent(this,Sonido.class);

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogo.setTitle("Atencion!!!");
    dialogo.setMessage("1. Ponte los Dos Auriculares. \n2. Escucha y Lee todo atentamente.");
    dialogo.setPositiveButton("Visto", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            startActivity(siguiente);
        }
    });
    dialogo.create();
    dialogo.show();
```

** (La clase Sonido NO es un Activity) Cabe recalcar que estoy generando apropósito la excepción precisamente para darme cuenta que no se esta generando el detalle de esta en el logcat.**

Comment: Que telefono es? Que version de android? Podrias agregar el codigo de las excepciones que quieres ver?

Comment: @sioesi ya he actualizado la pregunta

Comment: qué excepción genera ese tipo de acciones? Nunca he tenido la curiosidad de hacerlo jajaja

Comment: @Elenasys el hecho que pueda depurar desde el ide al telefono lo asume como conectado

Comment: @FuriosoJack Existe actualmente una respuesta similar, referente a los dispositivos HUAWE, la he agregado en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de buscar en foros de desarrollo en Android con problemas con los mismos dispositivos que tu, he encontrado esto, por suerte cuento justamente con un Huawei de prueba (Y tenia errores al verificar el GPS en aplicaciones hibridas SOLO EN ESTE MODELO, asi que nos viene la solucion siguiente bien a los dos :D )

Marca en tu dispositivo

```
*#*#2846579#*#*
```

Aparecera un menu que esta oculto por defecto

Vera un menu con varias opciones :

- Settings
- Phone info check
- NetworkSettings
- Upgrade
- recovery
- Battery charged menu

Entra a **Settings -> Log Setting ->** y aparecen las siguientes opciones

*Si no sale este menú lo más probable es que salga*

**Project Menu -> Background Settings -> Log setting** :

```
- Mobile log (desactivado)
- Model log (desactivado)
- Network log (desactivado)
- GPS log (desactivado)
- Baterry log (desactivado)
```

Activa Mobile log y GPS log (si es que ocuparas GPS en tu app) despues de hacer estos cambios reinicia el telefono.

**PASO 1**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PASO 2**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PASO 3**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: +1 es correcta =)  además con imagenes! Pero hay que limpiar la pantalla  ಠ_ಠ hehe

Comment: Wuajaja es el celular de prueba de la empresa xD siempre estamos en las mismas preguntas juju

Comment: Hey es un Nexus de Motorola? yo tengo uno igual! (Motorola Nexus 6) ya tiene de hecho el update a Android N.

Comment: Es un huawei :0

Answer (score 1):

Existe actualmente una respuesta similar, referente a los dispositivos HUAWEI:

**[Android 6.0 no muestra errores logcat Huawei](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/12958/android-6-0-no-muestra-errores-logcat) en dispositivo Huawei**

**La especificación de este dispositivo y otros de la marca HUAWEI, define escribir el código: *#*#2846579#*#* para abrir un menú que por default esta escondido.**

http://helpdesk.houdinisoft.com/products/huaweim865-ascend-264

Así que abriendo ese menú vamos a `Project Menu` > `Background Setting` > `Log setting` definimos mostrar el log con log switch y el nivel con log level setting.

Con esto ya puedo visualizar los mensajes en el LogCat.

---

Si lo anterior no lo corrige, dentro del **Android Monitor** debes revisar si el dispositivo se conecta correctamente, no debe tener el texto [OFFLINE], puede ser que el cable de conexión falle e incluso el driver pueda tener problemas (un simple restart puede corregir temporalmente el problema).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: practicamente la misma respuesta :D, saludos @Elenasys

Comment: esta pregunta ya se había respondido http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/12958/android-6-0-no-muestra-errores-logcat =)

Comment: :0! Excelente yo probe en mi telefono y no salian las mismas opciones por eso agregue mi respuesta

Comment: No Aceptare la respuesta de nadie y no necesito tu aprovacion Jajaja Ok no. Ami no me salio el menu se @sioesi aplique el de Elenasys y realmente tambien no me habia fijado en el logacat estaba apuntando hacia uno que estaba desconectado :V. Aunque las dos respuestas fueron de utilidad.

Comment: @FuriosoJack sioesi contesto primero y creo que es correcta. Me dio un poco de risa, aunque sinceramente me ha sucedido hace tiempo lo mismo en Eclipse, buscando porque no se despliega el LogCat, era otro Androide ಠ_ಠ