# ¿Cómo soluciono el error "La aplicación se ha detenido "?

Tags: android

Os explico, el código de la app no da error compila y ejecuta bien, ahora cuando se ejecuta la app en el móvil dice que se ha detenido la app, puede que el error sea por las activities ya que he creado múltiples activities puede que no entienda en cual orden debe arrancar cada activity y por ello se detenga, ahora con la actualización han cambiado el manifest y he probado con diferentes soluciones pero ninguna funciona y no encuentro nada que solucione mi problema, os dejaré el código de el manifest por aquí:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.audrysinfovisuproyectapp.definitiveapplicationformobile">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Registro">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Login"/>

        <activity android:name=".menu"/>

        <activity android:name=".MenuSC"/>

        <activity android:name=".MenuHTravel"/>

        <activity android:name=".BuysOptions"/>

        <activity android:name=".TravelOptions"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Así es como aparece el logcat cuando ejecuto la app:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo le estaría muy agradecida.

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo de tu actividad principal ? la de Registrar, y cuando te sale el error ? cuando entras a alguna de estas activities o cuando apenas inicias la app ?

Comment: Es importante el uso del LogCat, revisa mi respuesta, agrega el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat y con eso completaré mi respuesta.

Comment: El logcat aparece vacio.

Comment: El código de mi actividad principal no da error.

Comment: @mikudarkscx la aplicación es instalada de Play Store o desde Android Studio? tienes habilitado el "modo desarrollador" ?

Comment: Desde android studio y están habilitadas las opciones de administrador.

Comment: @mikudarkscx veo que tu dispositivo es un LG en el caso de Huawei se tiene que habilitar para mostrar mensajes en el LogCat revisa y realiza esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/12958/android-6-0-no-muestra-errores-logcat-huawei asegura estas seleccionando el paquete de aplicación correcto en el LogCat y comentame resultados!

Answer (score 1):

Noto que esto es algo que se pregunta comunmente **¿Cómo soluciono el error "La aplicación se ha detenido"?**, en cuanto al mensaje:

> "La aplicación se ha detenido" ('Unfortunately app has stopped')

en realidad es un mensaje de error genérico, el cual indica sucedió un problema en tu aplicación el cual obliga a cerrarla.

¿Como evitarlo?

Siendo un mensaje de error genérico, las causas que provocaron el cierre pueden ser diversas, es en realidad imposible determinar un conjunto de soluciones en las cuales se pueda determinar una solución.

Para evitarlo primeramente y muy importante el uso del [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=es-419)

[Escribir y ver registros en el LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=es-419)

> Cuando se produce una excepción en una app, en el monitor de logcat
> aparece un mensaje y luego el seguimiento de pila asociado que
> contiene vínculos al código. Esta función puede ayudarte a solucionar
> errores y mejorar la operación de la app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Acostumbra revisar el [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=es-419)y obtener el mensaje de error, eso determinara la solución real al problema.**

---

#### ...

#### Pendiente agregar LogCat por parte del OP para completar la respuesta.