# compartir captura de pantalla en huawei android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

**Tengo un metodo que crea una captura de pantalla del dispositivo y luego la comparto esa captura de pantalla. El problema que me surge es que funciona para  todos los dispositivos menos para huawei**

**Este codigo es quien ejecuta la captura**

```
 String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
```

**Este es el codigo que hace la accion de compartir**

```
imageFile.setReadable(true, false);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
        intent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartir imagen"));
```

**No se porque motivo no me deja enviar la captura de pantalla y tomar la captura. no me aparece el modal de compartir**

Comment: ¿Que no funciona el tomar la captura o enviar la imagen?

Comment: @Jorgesys al enviar la imagen

Comment: @jorgeys perdon, las dos no funciona

Comment: Bienvenido al mundo Huawei :-( @jonatadiaz , primeramente te sugiero habilites el LogCat y revises que error muestra https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/12958/android-6-0-no-muestra-errores-logcat-huawei eso ayudará a resolver este problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias @jorgesys.. seria la mejor solucion pero no tengo huawei.. el huawei de prueba esta en otro pais de donde me  estan reportando ese error.

Comment: La aplicación fue descargada desde Google Play Store?, si es así puedes revisar en Android Vitals > ANR & Crashes especificamente para ese modelo de dispositivo el error..

Comment: nono.. le genere yo la apk del android